# Is it possible to select and update an unknown value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

TABLE

```
ID      Person     Supervisor
1       Michele    2
2       James      4
3       Jacob      4
4       Francis    1
```

Let say Michele(1) leaves and I want her Supervisor(2) to take over supervising whoever Michele is supervising(Francis, 4)

```
SELECT id FROM TABLE WHERE supervisor = '1';
```

Would return me 2(Michele)

To update I would simply do

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET Supervisor = '2' <-- can this not be hard-coded but "selected" in an UPDATE statement?
WHERE Supervisor = '1';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a self-join.

```
UPDATE TABLE AS t1
JOIN TABLE AS t2 ON t1.supervisor = t2.id
SET t1.supervisor = t2.supervisor
WHERE t2.id = 1
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bH4BahTgeWP7HdGM633apd/0)

Comment: It's a MySQL extension, I don't think it's in standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inner join on the subquery

```
UPDATE TABLE t1 
INNER JOIN  (
   SELECT Supervisor FROM TABLE WHERE ID = '1' 
) T2 ON t2.Supervisor =  = t1.Supervisor

SET t1.Supervisor = t2.supervisor
```